# Sort enumerables with `nil` as last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

My data is

```
enumerable = [{rank:1}, {rank: nil}, {rank: 3}, {rank: 2}]
```

I want

```
sorted = [{rank:1}, {rank: 2}, {rank: 3}, {rank: nil}]
```

I tried with:

```
sort_by{|x| x.rank.to_i}
```

but `nil`s are put first. It has to be very efficient because I have to compute many times.

Comment: I want to sort a enumerable where nil values are at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
enumerable.sort_by { |h| h[:rank] || Float::INFINITY }
  #=> [{:rank=>1}, {:rank=>2}, {:rank=>3}, {:rank=>nil}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's sort based on two criteria:

1. rank nil/not nil
2. rank value

This way

```
enumerable.sort_by { |item| [item[:rank] ? 0 : 1, item[:rank]] }
```